How to determine whether you will obtain optical isomers in halogenation/free radical reactions?
I was going through some common free radicle reactions in my textbook (such as the Wurtz reaction, Fittig reaction, Kolbe's electrolysis, Ullmann reaction, etc.). Some examples showed that geometrical or optical isomers were also possible products.
For example, bromination of the C3 carbon in 2-chloro-3-methylpentane can give optical isomers. Is there any condition to this or can it happen whenever possible? Does the same go for geometrical isomers?

If either of the stereoisomer’s of the compound you mentioned are optically active to start bromination at C3 will still give an optically active compound on the other hand. If they are racemic, then there will be no optical activity after bromination.

@user55119 So it depends on the initial configuration of the compound and whether it is in a racemic mixture or not? Actually, the Fischer projection is given for the molecule I mentioned and it is shown that bromine can be substituted on either side of the Fischer at C3 to give different absolute configurations of that chiral center. However only one Fischer of the initial compound is shown where C3 has the s configuration. Does this imply that you can get a product that has a different configuration than the initial molecule when you are substituting on a chiral carbon?

LanternWatcher, Welcome to ChemSE. First off, Fischer projections have there place but they are not particular helpful here. A 3D representation is preferable (vide infra). Your 2-chloro-3-methylpentane does not show stereochemistry. It can be one of four stereoisomers (1-4). The radical formed at $\ce{C3}$ from 1-4 will be enantiomeric (red box). If the racemate 1 and 2 (optically inactive) is employed, the products 5 and 10 will be formed in the same amount (enantiomers) as will 6 and 9.  However, the ratio 5/10 to 6/9 is usually not equal to one. Both of these racemates will be optically inactive. If only one of the enantiomers 1 or 2 is employed, then the ratio of products will be the same as that of the racemate but each will be optically active.
Now consider the racemate 3 and 4. It also proceeds through the same enantiomeric radical as racemate 1 and 2. Therefore, the results will the same.


I see. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and diagrams.
